# Does ASP.NET have variables and procedures like ASP?

Tags: asp.net, function, variables, asp-classic

I came across a question here which had loops in ASP.NET

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) %>
```

This actually did work in ASP.NET. I then investigate if ASP.NET has variables like ASP but I could not find any solid answer.

[A demo of asp variable is here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_variable)

```
<%
dim name
name="Donald Duck"
response.write("My name is: " & name)
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but (in webforms anyway) it is there mainly for compatibility with old code and you should avoid using it that way. Includes, especially, will not work as you expect, as each file is compiled separately and includes are processed at **runtime** rather than compile time... you can use them for html, but not so much for code.

The new options of Master pages, custom and user controls, data binding, and other features are much better mechanisms for building your pages.  User controls, especially, are too often overlooked.

What you can do, for simple pages at least, is put one big server-side script block at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Page ... %>
<script runat="server" ... >
     Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        '...
     End Sub

     'Other variables and methods can go in here
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server" ...>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by separately? A single aspx is compiled in a single dll just because uses code blocs?

Comment: No - all the aspx files in an app will compile to the same dll. But they will be members of different classes. Includes are processed at **runtime**, and so the compiler doesn't know anything about a variable in an include file.

Comment: I guess the example still does not mention variables. I would like to see a flow of command <html> <asp code> <html><asp code> <loops etc>

Comment: The  correspondents of ASP variables are private fields, placed in the generated class by ASP .Net runtime. You can access them in the same ".aspx" file (in other include, code block), but you can't access in CodeFile or in CodeBehind, like you can do it with the runat="server" controls. To see the "flow" either search for the generated files in the ASP .Net temporary folder or deliberately write code which should not compile and, if the debug option in web.config is set to true, you will see the generated code in the Error Message (in the page).